# Does the Face of Boe take on any other forms earlier in its life?

Tags: doctor-who

As is suggested in *Last of the Time Lords*:

> Jark Harkness eventually becomes The Face of Boe

Are there any in-between stages that we see? Like his legs shrinking / falling off?

Answer (score 6):

This was brought up on a different site and I'm shamelessly ripping that off.

River gets a vortex manipulator "fresh off the wrist" of a "Pretty Boy Time Agent" (Jack maybe?) from Dorium Maldovar who is known to deal with the Headless Monks. The Headless Monks, as the name implies, like to take the heads off people but still keep them alive. Ta-da! The Face of Boe!

Though I'm not sure how he got to be so large, unless of course that's a physical manifestation of Jack's ego. ;)

Comment: Would have been nice to have linked to the original.

Answer (score 4):

Given that (spoilers unless you've seen through season 4):

> it is implied he is the Face of Boe in *The Last of the Time Lords* episode, we do not see Jack Harkness in any intermediate stage between his standard humanoid shape and his headless form.

This is provided you assume that what is implied is in fact true. However, given that the writer of the episode, Russell T. Davis, said ["it's couched in terms that are not absolute gospel"](http://www.nj.com/entertainment/tv/index.ssf/2009/06/russell_t_davies_talks_doctor.html), it is not officially the case. Depends on what you're inclined to believe ;) The answer to your original question remains unchanged.

Comment: We don't even know that he does become the Face of Boe. The latter doesn't exactly look like Jack. It could just be a coincidental name.

Comment: Note that [Russell T. Davis himself said: "it's couched in terms that are not absolute gospel"](http://www.nj.com/entertainment/tv/index.ssf/2009/06/russell_t_davies_talks_doctor.html). It seems like he was mainly aiming for humour, which comes from it being a possibility rather than a certainty.

Comment: You've spoilered the wrong bit...

Comment: @Pau The spoiler syntax is tricking me though. Could you please edit that correctly? (and tell me what I'm doing wrong?